# Undefined: req.file() outputs undefined even when using upload.single() middleware

Tags: node.js, express, multer

```js
// Models
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
      //  profileImage: {type: String, required: true}



});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema)



// Controllers
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});


exports.createProfile = (upload.single('profileImage'), function (req, res, next) {
    
    var profileData = {
        fullName: req.body.fullName,
        // profileImage: req.file
    }
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log('req.file: ', JSON.stringify(req.file));     
    console.log(profileData);
        Profile.create(profileData, function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {
            // console.log(err);
            res.end();
            return;
            // res.send(err);
        }
        Profile.create(function (err, profiles) {
            if (err) {
                res.end();
                // res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            
            res.json(profileData);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use middleware to add text and image at the same time in the MongoDB database. However, my fields aren't populated and when I try to print it out in the console it says req.file(): undefined. I've researched on the other issues and it states using 'upload.single()' will solve the problem. In my case, it didn't! The first section is my model view(Schema), the second section is my controllers' view.

Comment: Can you please turn this into a true [mcve]? Right now your code cuts off before it's done, and has some stuff in it that shouldn't be part of the problem, if the problem is what you say it is, so any exports (because you want a single runnable file), mongo access (hardcode the minimal data required as a response instead), passport auth (test code should not require creds), actual profile objects, etc. should all be removed by you to verify for yourself they're not part of this issue and give SO readers more concise, clearly problem-demonstrating code that they can help you with.

Comment: did you set input name = 'profileImage' ?

Comment: @Chiller Yes. In postman, I set the input as profileImage (form-data)